# How can I click_link a specific row with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tdd, capybara

I'm trying to write all my Capybara code to not use any CSS or funny matchers. For acceptance test purposes, I'm using Capybara to navigate only by button and link text that is visible to the user.

So I have a really simple test that asserts that an administrator can edit any user:

```
it 'allows an administrator to edit any user' do
  user = login_admin_user
  user1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  click_link "Users"
  current_path.should eq(users_path)
  click_link "Edit" # This is the problem
  current_path.should eq(edit_user_path(user1))
  fill_in "Last name", with: "Myxzptlk"
  click_button "Update User"
  page.should have_content("Myxzptlk")
end
```

Of course the problem line above is not specific enough; there will be 2 lines in the table (user and user1). I'm pretty new to TDD, so how do I use Capybara to select the correct link using only visible text?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use CSS selectors. I use them all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're avoiding 'CSS or funny matchers'. If you don't want to put them in your test, abstract them away into helper methods.

In my specs I have a helper method like this:

```
module FeatureHelper
  def within_row(text, &block)
    within :xpath, "//table//tr[td[contains(.,\"#{text}\")]]" do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

And then in my specs I can call it like:

```
within_row(user1.name) do
  click_link 'Edit'
end
```

The helper module goes inside the `spec/support` folder, and then gets loaded into my specs by doing:

```
config.include FeatureHelper, type: :feature
```

in my `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: You can use `within('td', text: text) do` instead of quiet unreadable `within :xpath, "//table//tr[td[contains(.,\"#{text}\")]]" do` if `Capybara.exact = false`. Thus you don't even need helper method for this

Comment: That will work if the text and the link are in the same cell. My xpath command will get the row that that cell is in.

Comment: Ouch. What about `within('tr', text: text) do`?

Comment: Your solution works great. I had to change :feature to :request, but that's it.